# Error on dynamic casting, where static cast works

Tags: .net, casting, f#

Casting `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>` to `int seq`.  I'd think this should work in static and dynamic cases pretty easily, and I'd think *anything* that works in static *should* work in dynamic, but here's the results I'm getting:

Static:

```
> List<int>() :> int seq;;
val it : seq<int> = seq []
```

Dynamic:

```
> List<int>() :?> int seq;;

  List<int>() :?> int seq;;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(115,1): warning FS0067: This type test or downcast will always hold

  List<int>() :?> int seq;;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(115,1): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    seq<int>    
is not compatible with type
    List<int>    
The type 'seq<int>' is not compatible with the type 'List<int>'
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the F# language.  It currently prevents dynamic casts to interfaces from anything except object.  Don has commented here that this limitation will be removed in a future version

> http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/57012

Comment: Wow, open since 2007... I don't think I even have browser tabs still open since then.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Apparently the issue you mentioned is already fixed because something like `[1] :> seq<int>` works. The problem is, as John states in his answer, that he's trying to _downcast_ to a _supertype_.

Comment: @daniel this bug is specific to interfaces. Base type or not is irrelevant

Comment: I wouldn't assume that "fixing" this issue is still planned - the current behavior is clearly enshrined in the spec, and the basic logic appears to be that downcasts should really be downward, as John Palmer suggests.

Comment: @JaredPar - `seq` is an interface - in particular it is exactly `IEnumerable<'t>`

Comment: @JohnPalmer i'm aware of that

Answer (score 2):

The problem is one of direction.

Using `:>` you go "towards" obj - a cast that will always succeed.

Using `:?>` you go in the opposite direction and the cast may fail.

As a result, you can't use `:?>` in your example as you are going in the wrong direction.

I think that thinking of them as static and dynamic casts is wrong.  Using upcast and downcast makes the distinction more obvious.

Comment: I think `dynamic`/`static` are complementary to `upcast`/`downcast`, the former being temporal (when the cast occurs) and the latter being directional (in an OO hierarchy sense).

Comment: @Daniel - the spec defines `upcast` and `downcast` in terms of `:>` and `:?>`.

Comment: @kvb: And `upcast`/`downcast` make sense. But the reasons similar operators in other languages are often called `static`/`dynamic` are also relevant to F#. The language of the spec is probably more useful, but I think it's an overstatement to say `static`/`dynamic` are wrong.

Comment: @Daniel - I agree that it's not "wrong" - it's just that it's potentially unhelpful.  If you think of `:?>` as a dynamic cast then the compiler's behavior in this scenario is hard to grok, but if you think of it as a downcast, then the fact that the compiler disallows "downcasts" to supertypes doesn't seem quite so strange.